# Split a single string into two or three variables in UNIX

Tags: unix

I have a `SESSION_TOKEN` which gets generated dynamically every 30 mins. Its character length is greater than 530 and approximately 536 characters will be there in it.

How can i split this string in UNIX scripting. Need help.

Comment: Its a bash script .Any suggestion on this?

Comment: How do you mean split? By delimiter? By length?

Comment: By length. Say i want to split the huge string into 3 variables based on length. 1 to 150, 151 to 300, 301 to end of string

Comment: Please edit the question (just click edit below the question), to get all the information together. Comments will get lost along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "cut" utility for this kind of fixed length work:

```
echo "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKK" | cut -c 10-20
CCCDDDDEEEE
```

The -c means "select by character" and the "10-20" says which characters to select.

You can also select by byte (using -b) which might make a difference if your data has some unusual encoding.

In your case, where you want to do multiple chunks of the same string, something like:

```
bradh@saxicola:~$ export somethingToChop="AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKK"
bradh@saxicola:~$ echo $somethingToChop | cut -c 1-10
AAAABBBBCC
bradh@saxicola:~$ echo $somethingToChop | cut -c 11-20
CCDDDDEEEE
bradh@saxicola:~$ echo $somethingToChop | cut -c 20-
EFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKK
```

Would probably be the easiest to understand.

Comment: Can you tick the "mark as answer" if you're OK with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bash variable expansion has substring operations built in:

```
$ string="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$ first=${string:0:8}
$ second=${string:8:8}
$ third=${string:16}

$ echo $first, $second, $third
abcdefgh, ijklmnop, qrstuvwxyz
```